# Google Glass: Why Get Directions card require glass to connect with the MyGlass app on Android or iPhone?

Tags: google-glass

When Google Glass is not connected with MyGlass App, Get Directions card in Glassware goes disabled but when connected it gets enabled. Why Google has enforced this kind of dependency, though Glass has it's inbuilt GPS feature? I didn't get any satisfactory explanation when googled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Glass does NOT have a GPS radio built-in, it relies on the GPS in the connected Android or iPhone. In addition, to get directions a connection to the internet is required (either via WiFi or by using bluetooth to connect through your Android or iPhone).

Answer (score 1):

Glass does not have a working onboard GPS. It uses the GPS of the phone it is tethered to.